# Decrease execution time in updating rows in PHP

Tags: performance, beginner, php, sql, database

Any tips on how the below code can be optimised for faster execution?

I have a table in postgres called staging with the below columns;

```
|person|colour|sport|
|Tom   |blue  |Tennis|
```

and a multi dimensional associative array that contains updates for each entry of the staging table, like so:

```
$updateArray =  array();
$updateArray['Tom']['color']='orange';
$updateArray['Tom']['sport']='golf';
```

I need to loop through the updateArray and update the entries of the staging data.

Here is what I have so far, where result2 is a query to select all the rows from the staging table. For each row returned I am looping through every entry of the updateArray, and then checking if it exists as one of the keys.

```
while ($row2 = pg_fetch_assoc($result2))
        {
            foreach ($array as $key => $value)
            {
                if ($key == $row2['person'])
                {
                    foreach ($value as $column_name => $column_value)
                    {
                        $row2[$column_name] = $column_value;
                    }
                }

            }
            fputcsv($fp, $row2);
        }
```

The above example is a simplified one, I need to update about 120,000 people and about 700 columns for each person multiple times so I am trying to get the above code more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the outer loop with a simple test:

```
if (array_key_exists($row2['person'], $array)) {
    $value = $array[$row2['person']];
}
```

Next, the inner loop can be replaced with a single merge:

```
$row2 = array_merge($row2, $value);
```

After some small refactorings, the code would look like this:

```
while ($row2 = pg_fetch_assoc($result2))
{
    if (array_key_exists($row2['person'], $array)) {
        fputcsv($fp, array_merge($row2, $array[$row2['person']]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, @nibra! One follow up question; if I wanted to use your above logic and extend it to work for numeric keys as well, would an efficient solution be to replace array_merge($row2, $array[$row2['person']])) with $row2 + $array[$row2['person_id']] where $row2['person_id'] results in a numeric key?

Comment: Yes, that should work. However, you will not have real control over the indices, i.e., you can't rely on fx. index 3 always being the `color`.